# Two inequalities involving the resolvent of sample covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, random-variables, numerical-linear-algebra, random-matrices

Let $X=[x_1 \dots x_n] \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$ be the data matrix where the $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times 1}$. Let the data be "centered at origin", so  $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = 0$. Let $C_X=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i x_i' \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ be the sample covariance matrix. Let $Q_X(z):=(C_X + zI_p)^{-1}$ be the resolvent of $C_X, $ and consider it for all $z > 0$. Note that, $Q_X(z)$ is defined for $z > 0,$ as $zI_p + C_X$ is positive definite (hence invertible), because $zI_p$ is positive definite and $C_X$ is positive semidefinite.

I'm trying to prove the following two upper bounds on the operator norm $||*||_{op}$

(1) $||Q_X(z)||_{op} \leq 1/z \forall z > 0$

(2) $||Q_X(z)X||_{op} \leq \sqrt{n} \forall z > 0$

EDIT: To solve (1), I used the fact that the eigenvalues of $Q_X$ are inverse of those of $C_X + zI_p$, and the eigenvalues of $C_X + zI_p$ are of the form $\lambda_i + z,$ where $\lambda_i, 1 \le i \le d$ are eigenvalues of $C_X$. Then we have: $||Q_X(z)||_{op}=$ maximum eigenvalue of $Q_X(z) = max_{1 \leq i \leq s} \frac{1}{\lambda_i + z} \leq 1/z.$

What about for the second problem?

Any hints or solutions appreciated!

Comment: using $C_X = \frac{1}{n}XX^T$ and $X = U\Sigma V^T$, (1) should be obvious. I'm not convinced that (2) is true.

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks, I edited the question with the answer of (1) I found in an alternate way. I'm still not sure how to use the SVD you used to prove (1) though/ So, by your symbols, $Q_X(z) = U(\frac{1}{n}\Sigma \Sigma^{T} + zI)^{-1}U^{T}$, and after taking the norms, we get: $||Q_X(z) || \le ||  (\frac{1}{n}\Sigma \Sigma^{T} + zI)^{-1}  || $. But I guess to show that the last quanity is $\leq 1/z,$ you'll use $\frac{1}{n}\Sigma \Sigma^{T} $ is positive semidefinite?

Comment: @user8675309 For (2), see P. 4 of https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01962077/document, where right above the Theorem 1, they specify this bound.

Comment: what you did is close 'in spirit' to what I did for (1).  However I'd suggest doing (1) via explicit use of SVD or Polar decomposition of $X$, because this gives you a mechanism to generalize to (2).  For (2), as a first cut I have singular values of $\frac{\sigma_i}{\frac{1}{n}\sigma_i^2 + z}$ which is 0 if $\sigma_i = 0$... supposing $X$ isn't the zero matrix, we can focus now only on $\sigma_j\gt 0$ and look at this sequentially: consider $z_k$ a positive decreasing sequence of z's where $z_k \to 0$, then

Comment: $\frac{\sigma_j}{\frac{1}{n}\sigma_j^2 + z_k} \leq \frac{\sigma_j}{\frac{1}{n}\sigma_j^2 + z_{k+1}}$, which implies a tight upper bound with a limitting z of 0, so the sup on the operator 2 norm is $\max_{j}\frac{\sigma_j}{\frac{1}{n}\sigma_j^2 }=\max_{j}\frac{n}{\sigma_j}$.  My guess is you left out something amount $X$ having some kind of standardized length for its columns.